# Removing RAID from Dell r510

Tags: 14.04, drivers, server, raid

We've a Dell Poweredge r510 server with the Ubuntu server, and has H700 raid controller card. Total five 750GB SAS drives are in the server.

System Information

```
$ dmesg | grep RAID
[    1.262175] scsi0 : LSI SAS based MegaRAID driver

$ lspci -v | grep "RAID" -A 12
02:00.0 RAID bus controller: LSI Logic / Symbios Logic MegaRAID SAS 2108 [Liberator] (rev 05)
Subsystem: Dell PERC H700 Integrated
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 32
I/O ports at fc00 [size=256]
Memory at df1bc000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
Memory at df1c0000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256K]
Expansion ROM at df100000 [disabled] [size=256K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: megaraid_sas
06:03.0 VGA compatible controller: Matrox Electronics Systems Ltd. MGA G200eW WPCM450 (rev 0a) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])     
Subsystem: Dell Device 02f1
Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 32, IRQ 19
```

Now want to remove the RAID and want to use all the disk separately. Is that possible to do this, please help me by sharing the knowledge how to do this.

Comment: "it depends" some raid controllers can be configured in your BIOS, others not. See https://serverfault.com/questions/851738/disable-hardware-raid-controller/851741 . You can try the megaraid tool, the commands are a bit obtuse (it has been a while since I played with megaraid and I do not recall all the syntax)

Answer (score 1):

This won't answer you question exactly, but I believe you would have to play around with the utilities referenced in here: http://hwraid.le-vert.net/wiki/LSIMegaRAIDSAS and here:https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Hardware_Raid_Setup_using_MegaCli#Delete_Raid_Device_.28Virtual_Drive.29.

Comment: Or disable RAID in the bios ....